# Java Servlets Without Extending a Servlet Class

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

I have inherited a large project that I am trying to better understand.

I have seen classes that act as servlets but that don't extend `HttpServlet` or implement any interfaces. Yet their methods are mapped to URIs.

How does this magic happen? Could it be something to do with Spring? `web.xml`? `pom.xml`?

Sorry if the question is too vague. I've been reading a number of tutorials on servlets, and they all seem to indicate the class must extend `HttpServlet` or similar. I'm at a loss as to how they work without that, so it is difficult to ask a more specific question.

Comment: maybe they are just plain old .jsp files? those can be loaded via a regular webserver like apache or whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be Java Enterprise Edition http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm

If the class has a @Path annotation, it could be a RESTful web service. Something like this:

```
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
    GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<html lang=\"en\"><body><h1>Hello, World!!</h1></body></html>";
    }
```

Modern Java EE Containers provide lots of functionality through very economical annotations.

Edit: The relevant part of the Oracle Java EE 7 tutorial is http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs002.htm#GILIK

Comment: Even if you use Java EE 6+ features, your class needs to specify that it extends from `HttpServlet` or that it implements `Servlet` interface.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the correction. I've changed my answer to suggest a RESTful web service.

Comment: It is indeed a RESTful web service. The servlet-mapping I have doesn't match what you linked to, but hopefully I'm on the right track now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above mentions, what you're seeing are Java annotations in general.

Here's a general link about that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html

Also the links above answer bring me to page not found pages but here are links I found discussing the @Path annotations and others that are associated with RESTful web services:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

Here's some snippets from the links:

```
The @Path annotation identifies the URI path template to which the resource responds and is specified at the class or method level of a resource. The @Path annotation’s value is a partial URI path template relative to the base URI of the server on which the resource is deployed, the context root of the application, and the URL pattern to which the JAX-RS runtime responds.

URI path templates are URIs with variables embedded within the URI syntax. These variables are substituted at runtime in order for a resource to respond to a request based on the substituted URI. Variables are denoted by braces ({ and }). For example, look at the following @Path annotation:

@Path("/users/{username}")
In this kind of example, a user is prompted to type his or her name, and then a JAX-RS web service configured to respond to requests to this URI path template responds. For example, if the user types the user name “Galileo,” the web service responds to the following URL:

http://example.com/users/Galileo
To obtain the value of the user name, the @PathParam annotation may be used on the method parameter of a request method, as shown in the following code example:

@Path("/users/{username}")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
The @Produces Annotation
The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or representations a resource can produce and send back to the client. If @Produces is applied at the class level, all the methods in a resource can produce the specified MIME types by default. If applied at the method level, the annotation overrides any @Produces annotations applied at the class level.

If no methods in a resource are able to produce the MIME type in a client request, the JAX-RS runtime sends back an HTTP “406 Not Acceptable” error.

The value of @Produces is an array of String of MIME types. For example:

@Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})
The following example shows how to apply @Produces at both the class and method levels:

@Path("/myResource")
@Produces("text/plain")
public class SomeResource {
    @GET
    public String doGetAsPlainText() {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String doGetAsHtml() {
        ...
    }
```

and

```
The @Consumes Annotation
The @Consumes annotation is used to specify which MIME media types of representations a resource can accept, or consume, from the client. If @Consumes is applied at the class level, all the response methods accept the specified MIME types by default. If applied at the method level, @Consumes overrides any @Consumes annotations applied at the class level.

If a resource is unable to consume the MIME type of a client request, the JAX-RS runtime sends back an HTTP 415 (“Unsupported Media Type”) error.

The value of @Consumes is an array of String of acceptable MIME types. For example:

@Consumes({"text/plain,text/html"})
The following example shows how to apply @Consumes at both the class and method levels:

@Path("/myResource")
@Consumes("multipart/related")
public class SomeResource {
    @POST
    public String doPost(MimeMultipart mimeMultipartData) {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public String doPost2(FormURLEncodedProperties formData) {
        ...
    }
}
```